# Python: easy, efficient way to check if determinant is 0 (mod large prime)?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, determinants

I want to check if an nxn matrix has 0 determinant. I don't care what the exact value is, just whether or not it is 0. The entries may be large integers, so I was thinking of doing Gaussian elimination mod a large prime p to limit the size of computations (I'm aware this makes the alg not exact). Doing this from scratch seems annoying, though; it seems like there must be something out there that has done this already, but I can't find it in the typical places like numpy libraries. Does anyone know of an existing solution?

Comment: `np.linalg.det` calls `r = _umath_linalg.det(a, signature=signature)`, where `https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.24.0/numpy/linalg/umath_linalg.cpp` is the source file.  My guess that's a 'brute-force' determinant calculation without any short cuts for special cases, especially if the `dtype` is float.

Answer (score 0):

Use Numpy

```
import numpy as np
matrix = [[1, 2], [4, 8]]
print(np.linalg.det(matrix) == 0)
```

See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html

I am not aware of specifically 0 check though